# systemd-ask-password prompt not displayed for vpn

Tags: systemd, openvpn

I have a working OpenVPN client config that uses a passphrase-protected private key.

If I run `openvpn` directly, I'm prompted for the passphrase and the client starts successfully.

But if I start it with `systemctl`, I'm **not** prompted for the passphrase, and the service never finishes initializing.

It appears that `systemd-ask-password` is waiting for the passphrase, but no prompt is displayed.

```
$ sudo systemctl start openvpn-myclient.service
$ systemctl status openvpn-myclient.service
● openvpn-myclient.service - OpenVPN instance ‘myclient’
   ...
   Status: "Pre-connection initialization successful"
    ...
   CGroup: /system.slice/openvpn-myclient.service
           ├─18997 openvpn --suppress-timestamps --config /path/to/client.conf
           └─18998 /path/to/systemd-ask-password --icon network-vpn Enter Private Key Password:
```

I can manually create a prompt to submit the passphrase:

```
$ sudo systemd-tty-ask-password-agent --query
Enter Private Key Password: ************************
```

I can also work around the issue by putting `askpass /path/to/passphrase` in my client.conf. That avoids the need for user input, but it also means keeping the passphrase in cleartext.

I'd like to understand what's going on, what I could do to get a prompt to show up, or how I could avoid putting the passphrase in cleartext.

How can I debug this further? I read the following man pages and it's still not clear to me what's at play.

- `systemd-ask-password`
- `systemd-tty-ask-password-agent`
- `systemd-ask-password-wall.service`

Comment: I have the same trouble. On my computer I can fix by letting the server run as root, by removing the "user openvpn" and "group openvpn" from the config file. But this is an extremly insecure solution. I prefer the have a clear pass phrase!

Answer (score 1):

After experimenting, it seems like systemctl will not prompt if the service is considered started just after the command, as is the case when `Type=simple`.

It worked when I used `Type=notify` and used sd_notify in the service itself to signal systemd the daemon has started, see [`sd_notify(3)`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_notify.html)

Then, if the process runs `systemd-ask-password`, it should appear on the prompt

```
user@machine:~$ sudo systemctl start daemon-example
daemon-example *************
```

#### Pure shell PoC example:

```
#!/bin/sh

export PW=$(systemd-ask-password "example:")

systemd-notify --ready  # only if the service itself does not call `sd_notify`

echo "$PW" # for PoC

# dummy service, replace by `exec /usr/bin/my-service` otherwise
while true; do
    sleep 10
done
```

```
# /etc/systemd/system/password-example.service
[Unit]
Description=example

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/tmp/example.sh
```

```
user@machine:~$ sudo systemctl start password-example.service
 example: ***
user@machine:~$ sudo journalctl -u password-example.service
[...]
systemd[1]: Starting example...
systemd[1]: Started example.
example.sh[8777]: yes
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you "used sd_notify in the service itself"? My service already uses `Type=notify`, but I'm not sure how to check whether it's using sd_notify.

Comment: @ivan edited with more details

Answer (score -1):

Using ‘askpass’ without arguments should work.